# Artifactory - create new version base on previous

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have maven-base ear file.
The ear contains lot of jars the built by same CI-CD process - monolith. 
I have implementation of incremental build, that improve the CI-CD times by build the artifacts that changed or affected only. and take the other artifacts from artifactory.
The problem is - when I start new version, I have to build all the artifacts in order to create the artifacts in artifactory the first time. This takes long of time. 
**Is there a quick way to copy all the artifacts from version 0.1 to version 0.2 in artifactory?**
In the beginning of version 0.2, The artifacts are the same.

Thanks

Comment: What does `This takes long of time.` this means? How many modules do you have? Which versions of the plugins, Maven, JDK do you use? Do you use parallelization?

Comment: "This takes long of time" - means the build of all the artifacts take something like half an hour. I have more then 600 modules (part of them are just parent poms), using maven 3-5-0, JDK 1.8, using parallelization.

Comment: Ok.. that sounds like an amazing build.. You should upgrade to most recent versions of Maven 3.8.6 and also use a most recent versions of JDK to build (JDK17).. Also very important use most recent versions of all plugins... And is it really the build time or testing / downloading artifacts? etc.?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

It's not that straight forward.
Personally I think it's not the right way to go. You should probably break your internal dependencies based on their lifecycles, and reuse existing versions instead of rebuilding them.

**In more details:**

Technically, you can use the [JFrog CLI's copy command](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-CopyingFiles) to copy files in Artifactory. You can also use the [Copy Item](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CopyItem) API directly if you prefer. Copy is a cheap and quick operation in Artifactory because of its checksum based storage (the content is stored only once).

But, that's not enough, mainly because of Maven.

Maven uses a file path format which contains the version - both as a folder and in the file names. The Maven artifacts file path format is (simplified): `/<group>/<artifact>/<version>/<artifact>-<version>.<ext>`. For example, the `jar` file of the artifact `org.acme:foo:0.1` will have a file like: `/org/acme/foo/0.1/foo-0.1.jar`.
It means that copying files from folder of `0.1` to `0.2` is not enough, you also need to rename them accordingly.

And that's still not enough - Maven also embeds the the version in files, mainly in the `pom` file. It means that copying it is also not enough, you need to modify the content of that xml file.

But, it also depends on how you use Artifactory. The best practice is to publish also a build-info when you upload to Artifactory. That usually means that Artifactory stores properties on the files, properties which are specific to the build as part of which they were created and uploaded. These properties are also copied as part of the copy operation mentioned above, and you should remove them from the new version.

To do all of that you can probably write a simple script which lists the files, copy and rename the files, adjust the content of the `pom` file, and remove the properties.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I think about another option: maybe I will use maven range version to use the previous version if new version of the artifact is not available. This way, I will build and deploy the artifacts that changed or affected only, and not duplicate the files in artifactory.